# C++ Component System Issue

Tags: c++, entity, components

I'm trying to get a small *Entity/Component System* to work in C++. So far it's ok, it doesn't have much to it, but I'm facing an issue.
Here is my current code:

```
class Entity {
public:
    // [...]
    template<typename T, typename ...Args>
    bool AddComponent(Args... args) {
        std::type_index tid = std::type_index(typeid(T));
        if (_Components[tid] == nullptr) {
            _Components[tid] = std::make_shared<T>(args...);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    template<typename T>
    std::shared_ptr<T> GetComponent() {
        // Issue here
        std::type_index tid = std::type_index(typeid(T));
        return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(_Components[tid]); // return nullptr if no component
    }

    template<typename T>
    bool RemoveComponent() {
        std::type_index tid = std::type_index(typeid(T));
        if (_Components.erase(tid) == 1) return true;
        return false;
    }

    private:
        std::map<std::type_index, std::shared_ptr<Component>> _Components;
};
```

As seen above, it's pretty straightforward, each component is derived from a base class `Component` and is used as follow:

```
class Component;
class MyComponent: public Component {
    // [...]
    MyComponent(int foo_): foo(foo_) {}
    int foo;
}

Entity e;
e.AddComponent<MyComponent>(42);
std::cout << e.GetComponent<MyComponent>()->foo; // 42
e.RemoveComponent<MyComponent>();
std::cout << e.GetComponent<MyComponent>()->foo; // Error
```

The error is logic and I understand why, but my question would be how to prevent a error when calling a `Component` that has been removed, and thus is `nullptr` without crashing the program ?

Is a simple try/catch enough ? How should it be implemented here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either check the pointer:

```
auto ptr = e.GetComponent<MyComponent>();
if(ptr) ptr->foo();
```

Or add a `HasComponent` method:

```
template<typename T>
bool HasComponent() {
    std::type_index tid = std::type_index(typeid(T));
    return _Components.find(tid) != _Components.cend();
}
```

You can also modify `GetComponent` so as it doesn't insert a `nullptr` in the map:

```
template<typename T>
std::shared_ptr<T> GetComponent() {
    std::type_index tid = std::type_index(typeid(T));
    return (_Components.find(tid) == _Components.cend()) ? nullptr : std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(_Components[tid]);
}
```

Comment: I guess I have no choice than checking if the `Component` exist every time ! And small thing, shouldn't `HasComponent` return a boolean instead of a `std::shared_ptr<>` ?

Comment: @Usiten Yeah, right, copy and paste error. Thank you.